# Real time calling functionality between 2 Cisco IP phones each connected to a PC

Tags: java, sip, voip, tapi, cisco-jtapi

I have 2 Cisco IP phones each connected to a PC through splitters with phone's mic output to PC speaker input and vice versa.

I have a portal with an on-screen dialer for dialing from one phone to another. I have used Cisco WebDialer api to make call and it is working fine. Now, the WebDialer api does not have any function/method for receiving/accepting call at the receiver end.

I found Cisco JTAPI which has a MakeCall.java class and also a Receiver.java class. I tried this but got errors and exceptions related to TAPI modem. How is JTAPI related to TAPI modem. Can i actually make and receive calls using JTAPI? Am i moving in the right direction?

Is there anything else or anyother api that i can use to communicate between 2 Cisco IP phones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Cisco phone is not depends on PC. It just provides 2-port HUB to connect PC and phone to one wall jack.
To make a call with 2 phones you need a PBX. The Cisco UCM is native for Cisco phones but costs a lot of money. You may use a free PBX like asterisk.
BTW. Cisco JTAPI works closely with Cisco UCM. It can't work alone.